Apache Ignite - Why TcpDiscoverySPI taking 2 sec on Windows to fail while sending Join request message
I have configured TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder with 5 nodes. I have started the first node and watched how long it takes to start the first node. It took a lot of time 4 min, The log shows that each join request message failed after 2 sec. This only happening on windows. On Linux it is very fast like milli seconds. The Ignite configuration isa same on both platforms.
Any reason for that?? and how to reduce the join time with configuration? Same Java version is used on windows and Linux.
Windows logs:
2024-07-02 **15:48:32**,151 UTC+0530 DEBUG [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi -- Failed to send join request message [addr=as-node1:47508, msg=Connection refused: getsockopt]
2024-07-02 **15:48:34**,158 UTC+0530 DEBUG [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi -- Failed to send join request message [addr=as-node1:47502, msg=Connection refused: getsockopt]
2024-07-02 **15:48:36**,165 UTC+0530 DEBUG [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi -- Failed to send join request message [addr=as-node3:47508, msg=Connection refused: getsockopt]
2024-07-02 15:48:38,172 UTC+0530 DEBUG [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi -- Failed to send join request message [addr=as-node3:47509, msg=Connection refused: getsockopt]
2024-07-02 15:48:40,177 UTC+0530 DEBUG [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi -- Failed to send join request message [addr=as-node3:47503, msg=Connection refused: getsockopt]
2024-07-02 15:48:42,183 UTC+0530 DEBUG [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi -- Failed to send join request message [addr=as-node2:47503, msg=Connection refused: getsockopt]
2024-07-02 15:48:44,190 UTC+0530 DEBUG [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi -- Failed to send join request message [addr=as-node3:47500, msg=Connection refused: getsockopt]

Linux Logs:
2024-06-26 **11:47:55**,219 UTC+0530 DEBUG [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi -- Failed to send join request message [addr=Leno-5:47500, msg=Connection refused]
2024-06-26 **11:47:55,222** UTC+0530 DEBUG [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi -- Failed to send join request message [addr=Leno-3:47507, msg=Connection refused]
2024-06-26 **11:47:55,224** UTC+0530 DEBUG [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi -- Failed to send join request message [addr=Leno-2:47507, msg=Connection refused]


please share you configuration, the most interesting part is TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder

Try adjusting TcpDiscoverySpi#socketTimeout to a lower value.
This is a known issue on Windows. When the port is not open, Linux returns an error immediately, but Windows waits for the specified timeout.
